# Adobe Bridge Digital Asset Manager for a Team

Tags: adobe-bridge

Just looking for any insight on using Adobe Bridge for a Team to manage and organize photos, videos and purchased stock files

My company currently has a few CC licenses and in researching on Bridge it looks like you can download the software for free, but for a single user, and doesn't offer the option to share files to your team members.

And in order to use the team option, you'll need the full Creative Cloud package for each license/team member,

What we are trying to accomplish is being able to share images from photo shoots, be able to archive, meta tag with categories and details, create contact sheets from selected images and overall have an archiving system,

Any insight on using Adobe Bridge would be great as well as any cost information you can think of,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a solution to store photos between your team and manage all your assets in between. In fact, Adobe Bridge doesn't suit your needs after all, Bridge only manages your local assets on your computer. And there is no server version that brings all your team members together en masse.

What you may need is a DAM Server (Digital Assets Management) server, you can buy a license for each user you want to include.

Some solutions could be rented online and others you can download on a server to be among your team members. You can assign an administrator to manage the system and grant each user a privilege on your DAM server. This server can classify users in groups and give privileges to each group and record users activities on the server so that it is easier for the system administrator to track team activities and know who did what. it may keep versioning of the same photo or picture and find duplicates, have a keywording and tagging system, commenting, chatting, face detection, and Geo-location tag. besides all the image operations you may need like rotating, scaling, printing ...etc.

With a local DAM will never be allowed to share your assets with your team members, what you need is a DAM server and unfortunately, there are no cheap or free servers. but it is worth the money and it is a very big time saver.